# Does Aura of Menace from multiple Lantern Archons stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, stacking

> **Aura of Menace (Su):** Any hostile creature within a 20-foot radius of
>   an archon must succeed on a Will save (DC 13) to resist its effects.
>   The save DC is Charisma-based, and includes a +2 racial bonus. Those
>   who fail take a –2 penalty on attacks, AC, and saves for 24 hours or
>   until they successfully hit the archon that generated the aura. A
>   creature that has resisted or broken the effect cannot be affected
>   again by the same archon's aura for 24 hours.

The penalty from the [Lantern Archon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/archon/lantern-archon/summoned-creature-lantern-archon)'s aura of Menace appears to be typeless, if you summoned multiple lantern Archons and a creature failed the save from all of them would they suffer only a -2 or the cumulative penalty from all of them?

Comment: Were auras of menace *to* stack, an absurdly large lantern archon strike force could teleport in and reduce even a demon lord's AC and — O, my! — *saving throws* to nothing in a round: even [Baphomet](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/demon/demon-lords/demon-lord-baphomet) will roll multiple 1s when surrounded by *hundreds* of lantern archons, and Baph'll be screwed for *1 day!* Plenty of time for the solars to come in and mop up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Rules as written: Yes, they stack

Unless the source is from a spell, which do have [the wording saying that spell effects do not stack with each other](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Stacking-Effects) if they are from the same spell, in general, **penalties stack regardless of their type**.

**Spell-like abilities** behave like spells and should follow that same ruling.

However, **Supernatural Abilities** are not spells, and do not have that ruling about them ([among others](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Supernatural-Abilities-Su-)).

> [Stacking](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Stacking)
>
> Stacking refers to the act of adding together bonuses or penalties that apply to one particular check or statistic. Generally speaking, **most bonuses of the same type do not stack**. Instead, only the **highest bonus applies**. **Most penalties do stack**, meaning that their values are added together. Penalties and bonuses generally stack with one another, meaning that the penalties might negate or exceed part or all of the bonuses, and vice versa.

### But they probably should not stack

Everytime someone asks if something stacks on the boards, they get mixed results, but that's because the rules are a little vague on that subject.

It is known that [bonuses of the same type, or same source, never stack](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9sgk).

Spells, also, do not stack, regardless of their bonus or penalty type if they are from the same spell (see [Ray of Enfeeblement](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/ray-of-enfeeblement)). They will stack if they are different spells with different types (see [Mage Armor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mage-armor) and [Shield](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shield) spells).

This exact same question ("[Does Aura of Menace Stack?](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2sida?Does-Aura-of-Menace-stack)") was posted on paizo's forum a while ago, with mixed results.

It seems that the intent of the devs are that "bonuses/penalties from same sources do not stack. But there is no definitive answer on this.

Comment: This is a great answer—except that you make a claim about the authors’ intent without backing it up. You have nothing from Paizo themselves that says this is what they meant. You have two rules that say certain, specific, named things don’t stack—that isn’t evidence that anything outside of those two things isn’t supposed to stack either. I certainly agree with you that they probably were not meant to stack, *but there is no real evidence, it’s just opinion*. Ditch the “rules as intended” label, and this becomes an excellent answer. As is, I must—we all should—downvote.

Answer (score 1):

**No, they do not stack.** However, you can be affected by (and save against) multiple auras at the same time.

From the [PFSRD - Combining Magical Effects](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Combining-Magic-Effects)

> Spells that provide bonuses or penalties on attack rolls, damage rolls, saving throws, and other attributes usually **do not stack with themselves**.

Comment: The quote discusses spells. Aura of menace is not a spell. Does the quote apply to it for some other reason?

Comment: He is not wrong though. http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Stacking

Comment: @Thanuir While the quotation discusses spells, the [*section*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magic.html#combining-magic-effects) discusses magical effects *generally*, each paragraph using *effect* instead of spell in its opening sentence. This *is* a horrible (and maddeningly [persistent!](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/magicOverview.html#combining-magical-effects)) editorial choice, but here taking *spells* as shorthand for *magical effects* is a reasonable judgment call.